# filter excel data with python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

I want to filter out country belonging to the tuple **need** and display every data in the records for countries after filter...

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import xlwt
import xlrd


file = 'ida.xlsx'
data = pd.read_excel(file)
need =("Algeria", "Angola", "Argentina", "Bangladesh", "Belize", "Benin", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Botswana", "Brazil", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", 
"Cameroon", "Cape Verde", "Central African Rep.", "Chad", "Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo, Dem. Rep.", "Congo, Republic", 
"Costa Rica", "Cote d'Ivoire", "Cuba", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Ethiopia", "Fiji", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Ghana", "Grenada", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Honduras", 
"India", "Indonesia", "Iran", "Jamaica", "Jordan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Kyrgyzstan", "Laos", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Madagascar", "Malawi", 
"Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Marshall Island", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mexico", "Mongolia", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", 
"Namibia", "Nepal", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Pakistan", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Rwanda", "Samoa", 
"Sao Tome and Principe", "Senegal", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Solomon Islands", "South Africa", "Sri Lanka", "St Vincent and the Grenadines", "St.Kitts", "St.Lucia", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Swaziland", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "Togo", "Tonga", "Tunisia", "Turkey", 
"Uganda", "Uruguay", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela", "Viet Nam", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe")
for i in data.index:
    filt = data[data['Recipient'][i] == need]
    print(filt)
```

i get 
.

> > > ============== RESTART: C:/Users/robinson/Desktop/next set/done.py =============
> > >       Empty DataFrame
> > >       Columns: [Recipient, Unnamed: 1, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018]
> > >       Index: []
> > >
> > > instead of data of each country and year...

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: What did you get when you run `print(data)`? Maybe you have to clear all unwanted content (first excel lines) of your dataframe. Have you done that?

Comment: yes i've run ```print(data)``` and this is what i got                                                 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Recipient, Unnamed: 1, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018]
Index: []
>>>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget the `for` loop and just use:

```
# for i in data.index: # <-- remove this
filt = data[data['Recipient'].isin(need)]
```